# Applying ID to canvas with react-three-renderer

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I'm using react-three-renderer to load up a few 3d objects. I'd like the canvas it creates to have a specific id but I can't seem to find where I can create this.

No matter where I apply `id` to my `render()`, it continually throws the error message of:

```
Warning: Foreign prop id found in react3.
```

It errors in react3, scene and perspectiveCamera elements.

The renderer is creating a canvas like,

```
<canvas width="1731" height="1209" style="width: 1731px; height: 1209px;"></canvas>
```

Where I need it as,

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1731" height="1209" style="width: 1731px; height: 1209px;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `id`, but instead you should use a reference to the canvas by using `React.createRef()`

```js
import React from 'react';
import THREE from 'three';

class WebGLLayer extends React.Component {
    canvasRef = React.createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
        // This will have a reference to the <canvas> element
        console.log(this.canvasRef.current);

        // You can assign it to your WebGLRenderer as follows:
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: this.canvasRef.current,
            alpha: true,
            depth: false,
        });
    }

    onWindowResize() {
        // Renderer will remember its canvas on setsize()
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <canvas ref={this.canvasRef} className="canvasClass" />
        );
    }
}
```

This reference to the canvas element has a `.current` property which is the rendered `<canvas>` DOM element, and it will be available for use on `componentDidMount()`. You can then assign this reference as your `WebGLRenderer`'s canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use IDs to refer to elements created by React - in fact, it's not possible in your case, without changing the core functionality of react3 (which react-three-renderer uses).

You should instead use refs - more information here: https://www.javascriptstuff.com/use-refs-not-ids/

Comment: Thanks, I went down the refs. Unfortunately I'm using a non-React library that requires a canvas id in to be supplied. Ugh.

Comment: Which non-react library? I've been doing some work with react and threejs myself in the past week.